# Should dairy products be consumed when having a fever?

Tags: nutrition, milk

I have always been told that when having a fever I shouldn't drink milk or consume dairy products as they would increase my temperature. Is this true?

Comment: I suspect this is more to do with the body's difficulty in digesting milk when ill, and not that it will add degrees to the body temperature

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not true. They won't increase your temperature. But for some people, it can cause extra mucus to be formed which can complicate your illness. [Source](http://www.webmd.com/cold-and-flu/flu-guide/what-to-eat-when-you-have-the-flu?page=2).